# Enforced Folder Structure in Java for Uploaded Files

Tags: java, design-patterns, junit

I am looking to create a system where a clearly-defined local filesystem folder structure follows a specific pattern.  Programmatically or manually violating the pattern should throw an exception.

For example:

```
company/
  |
  ---> building/
           |
           ----> images/
           |        |
           |        --->image.jpg
           |
           |---> issues/
                    |
                    -----> current/
                    |
                    -----> archive/
```

The pattern above is simplified vs. reality (imagine 7 levels deep and wide).

My thinking is that I can use Junit to make sure the pattern is met.  I started writing some custom code with the Paths API in Java 7 over Spring MVC, though it seems like there has to be a faster way that's less error prone.  (Some framework already created?  Visitor design pattern?)  I would want the application to enforce the pattern rather than the OS or an external script.  Also, the directory name can be a dynamically generated numeric ID.

Admins: I'll happily remove this question if it's deemed not constructive.  I looked around stackoverflow and didn't find a suitable answer.

UPDATE:
For more clarity, here's what I am doing now:

```
public static Path getCompanyDirectory(Integer companyId) {
    //getRootFolder returns the folder above "company"
    return Paths.get(File.separator+getRootFolder()+File.separator+COMPANIES+File.separator+companyId.toString());
}

public static void createCompanyDirectory(Integer companyId) {
    createDirectories(getCompanyDirectory(companyId));
}

public static Path getBuildingDirectory(Integer companyId, Integer buildingId) {
    return Paths.get(File.separator+getRootFolder()+File.separator+COMPANIES+File.separator+companyId.toString()+
         File.separator+BUILDING+File.separator+buildingId);

}    
public static void createBuildingDirectory(Integer companyId, Integer buildingId) {
    createDirectories(getBuildingDirectory(companyId, buildingId));
}

private static void createDirectories(Path dir) {
    try {
        if (Files.notExists(dir)) {
            Files.createDirectories(dir);
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
//the rest omitted for brevity
```

Comment: In what context are you using this? You say "programmatically or manually violating the pattern show throw an exception". Is the aim to monitor the file system for changes (from any source) and validate regularly, immediately? Why would you use JUnit in this case? You can run validation using assertions without JUnit.

Comment: Context of this question is highly vague, can you please elaborate what actually you want to do?

Comment: If my application creates a directory that doesn't follow the stated pattern and naming-convention, throw an exception.  If a user manually creates a directory that doesn't follow the stated pattern or naming-convention, throw an exception.  JUnit can be used after build. I am looking to create a directory structure so that files are neatly and predictably categorized.

Comment: As an example of the context, I want to be certain that the images for a particular company's building will be found in /company/building/images and not /company/images or /company/building/img.  A pre-defined folder structure eliminates chances of typos during development since we can refer to folders with static strings or a value from a resource bundle.

Comment: Build a tree of your correct and actual structure and test them for equality

Comment: Right, you got my drift.  That's something that I can do in Junit after the updated code that I included.  I was looking to see whether there was some other cleaner approach to the "build a tree" part given that there are a lot of branches.

Comment: Have an upvote, @blank